# How to write a regular expression to remove and add characters at a specified position?

Tags: regex, powershell

I need to write a regular expression to convert `vol0eaec8f32c9a98654_00000001.` to `vol-0eaec8f32c9a98654`. I am doing this in PowerShell script.

I tried using the below code to strip everything after `_`

```
$s = "vol0eaec8f32c9a98654_00000001."
$s.Substring(0, $s.IndexOf('_'))
```

Thank you

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: I am using PowerShell, i tried using `.substring()` to strip the last characters, I need help solving this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, it's better an idea to ask `how to achieve x` instead of `how to achieve x using y`. This is because of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

A regular expression is suitable to your problem, but not the way you'd think. It's used for error checking. Actual string manipulation is done with `.Replace()`, `IndexOf()`, and `Substring()` like so,

```
$s = vol-0eaec8f32c9a98654
# If the string starts with vol and contains an underscore,
# pick substring from 0 to underscore and replace vol with vol-
if($s -match '^vol.+_.*') { 
    $t = $s.Substring(0, $s.IndexOf('_')).Replace('vol', 'vol-')
    $t
} else {
    Write-Host "Invalid string: $s"
}
# output
vol-0eaec8f32c9a98654
```

To see why error check is there, consider a string without underscore:

```
$s = "vol0eaec8f32c9a9865400000001."
$s.Substring(0, $s.IndexOf('_')).Replace('vol', 'vol-')                                                         Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length"
At line:1 char:1
+ $s.Substring(0, $s.IndexOf('_')).Replace('vol', 'vol-')
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

Boom! Since `IndexOf` didn't find an underscore, the `Substring` method throws an exception.

How about if there isn't `vol`? Let's see:

```
# NB vool instead of vol
$s = "vool0eaec8f32c9a98654_00000001."
$s.Substring(0, $s.IndexOf('_')).Replace('vol', 'vol-')                                                         
vool0eaec8f32c9a98654
```

Uh uh! Now the underscore part is processed nicely, but the start of the string wasn't changed. That's because `Replace` looks for a pattern and replaces it *if it finds one.* If it didn't, that's OK.

Moral of the story: always check for error conditions. Regular expressions often are very good for input validation, and for some cases excellent tools for replacing too. Don't get too hung on the idea that you *need* to use a regex - unless you are taking a regex class.

As a side note, even input validation doesn't need a regex. Using `IndexOf` works just fine. I'd usually prefer a regex, but for some scenarios a few index lookups would actually be more easy to read than a complex regex pattern.

```
# Look for vol and _. The underscore must be after vol.
# If both patterns exist, the substring doesn't ever get invalid argument
if( ($s.IndexOf('vol') -ge 0) -and ($s.IndexOf('_') -gt $s.IndexOf('vol')) ) {
  $s.Substring(0, $s.IndexOf('_')).Replace('vol', 'vol-')
} else {  Write-Host "Invalid string: $s" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
$s = $s -replace "vol","vol-"
```

Answer (score 0):

My requirement changed after I posted this question, the strings were in two formats `vol0eaec8f32c9a98654_00000001.` and `vol0eaec8f32c9a98654`, the below regex worked for me, to convert them into valid volume Ids:

```
    if ($volumeId.IndexOf('vol') -ge 0) {           
            $validId = $volumeID -replace "_[^ ]*$" -replace "vol", "vol-" 
    }
    else { Write-Host "Invalid Volume ID: $volumeId" }
```